# C++ STL Container requirements - Post condition confusion

Tags: c++, containers, language-lawyer

I am currently looking at implementing a custom container which needs to be compatible with STL algorithms and therefore must meet the C++ container requirements as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

In that documentation the `Methods and operators` table states, that the expression `a = b` has the post condition of `a == b`. I am heavily confused by this.
As the table entry for this expression states:

> destroys or move-assigns all elements of `a` from elements of `b`

To my understanding, moving an object comes with the expectation that the moved object (source object?) will be left in a valid but undefined state. Therefore, the condition `a == b` cannot be met in my opinion.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  It should say *copy-assigns all elements of a from elements of b*

Comment: b may be r-value result of function call

Comment: The STL is the wrong term. It is not the name of the standard library, it's an old library from which many parts were migrated into what is now the standard library. [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What would you use if you wanted to refer to the C++ standard library in less than 8 syllables/20 characters?

Comment: @MaxLanghof If you are under an 8 character constraint, you can probably get away with "stdlib". "the std library" is not very long either. Edit : Misread the end of your comment as "in less than 8 characters?".

Comment: @MaxLanghof `std::` or "namespace std" depending on if I were writing or talking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) is abridged and adapted from the standard for readability. In this case it oversimplifies the requirements, which have to distinguish between the different value categories (as you correctly reasoned). Or maybe the two separate assignment cases (which do not appear consecutively in the table in the standard) have been merged by accident. Either way, cppreference is currently wrong.

Here is what the (current draft) standard says:

http://eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-4

For move-assignment:

> **Expression:** `a = rv` (where `rv` is a non-const rvalue)
>   **Return type:** `X&`
>   **Operational Semantics:** All existing elements of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed
>   **Ensures:** `a` is equal to the value that `rv` had before this assignment
>   **Complexity:**   linear

For copy-assignment:

> **Expression:** `r = a`
>   **Return type:**  `X&`
>   **Ensures:** `r == a`
>   **Complexity:** linear